# Convert Text to Date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to I convert a text value like "18/06/11" to a date format like "2011-06-18"?

I have tried the following

convert(char,[InstrumentText], 106)

but the value just stays in the same format

Thanks

Comment: Because you are converting it to char. Try converting to datetime. Why do you store date information in a char datatype in the first place?

Comment: For future reference DO NOT STORE DATES AS STRINGS! It will make your life quite miserable.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format for your string would appear to be 103.

More importantly, you need to convert to a `datetime` not to a `char`:

```
convert(date,[InstrumentText], 103)
```

If you then want to convert it back to a string in the format yyyy-mm-dd, you can do:

```
convert(varchar(10), convert(date,[InstrumentText], 103), 120)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '18/06/11' , 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed this from sqlusa.com:

SELECT CAST([InstrumentText] AS datetime)

Comment: Thanks, but i get the following error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.